# Statistics, Find CDF with some information given in example

Tags: statistics

A certain river flows every year. The low water mark is set at 1 and the high level water mark has CDF;  FY = 1-(1/y^2). 1<=y<=inf.

If the low water mark is reset at 0 and we use a unit measurement that's 1/10 of the one used previously. The high level mark becomes Z = 10(y-1).

Find the CDF of Z.

Comment: FZ(z) = FY((z + 1)/10). 0<=z<=inf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CDF method of transformation

$F_Y(y) = 1-\frac{1}{y^2}$

$Z = 10(Y-1)$

$F_Z(z) = P(Z\le z) =P(10(Y-1) \le z) = P(Y\le \frac{z}{10}+1) = 1-\frac{100}{(z+10)^2}$

$$F_Z(z) = 1-\frac{100}{(z+10)^2}, 0\le z \le \infty$$

Comment: But it is not Fz(z) = 1 - 1/(z/10+1)^2?

Comment: Yes you are right, if you simplify that you will get the one that I have written